# Is there something like Gatherer but with inventory management?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx) is great (sort of) for building decks, but I'd like the additional filter of specifying the search specifically to the cards I own.  Is this a feature I'm just not seeing or is there an app of some sort that does this?  I'd also like if it were always as up to date as Gatherer is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an additional resource, if you have an iOS or Android device, there is an app called [Decked](http://www.deckedbuilder.com/index.html) that I use for deck building. There are a lot of nice features to this app. Not only does the search criteria make it easy to find cards, it lets you create and manage decks right in the app. There are a lot of other useful features: it also allows you to test decks you've made in the app; you can have it automatically add the appropriate amount of land; you can see prices from multiple sources such as TCGPalyer and CardShark. Decked includes the ability to manage your collection so you can select cards and build decks exclusively using what you already own.

The downside to this is that, while there is a free lite version on iOS, the app does cost money if you want the ability to manage your collection: $3.99 on [iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id397090691) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deckedbuilder.deckedbuilder&hl=en), $5.99 on iPad, plus $2.99 for the collection manager (so between $7 and $9 total to get the management feature). But for the small cost, I find the benefits of this app are far beyond what I get with online search engines and collection trackers.

Comment: That's cool. They have a desktop version too and all 3 apps stay in sync over iCloud.  Downside is you have to buy 3 apps.  But not bad in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: My son and I both have the iOS and OSX versions installed and share decks all the time. Decked is really clean and always updates with the latest cards within a few days of release by Wizards.

Comment: The search function is also really good in my opinion, since it provides full text search.

Answer (score 8):

To manage my collection, I have used [deckbox.org](http://www.deckbox.org). Since it uses gatherer as a "database" to know what all the cards are, it stays up to date with the current set. You will have to tell it what cards you do own however, so there is some up front work to tell the collection manager what you have.

It also uses [magic.tcgplayer.com](http://magic.tcgplayer.com) to let you know both the individual pricing of your cards and the contents of your entire collection.

Comment: deckbox is nice!  I especially like the pricing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Mtgdb.Gui**, a free program I wrote can do this.

The screenshot below demonstrates searching by text (left arrow) while limiting the search to the cards from collection you own (right arrow)

[image: a button to narrow down search to owned cards only]

Besides managing your physical collection, you can import your collection and decks from [Magic The Gathering Online](https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/magic-online-products-game-info), build your decks in Mtgdb.Gui and load them back into MTGO.

---

[Wiki](https://github.com/NikolayXHD/Mtgdb/wiki) to get more information and screenshots

Comment: It looks like this is your site, in which case we require you to explicitly disclose your affiliation to it. Please see our advertising policy: [how to not be a spammer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Almost correct. It's not my site, but the program is written by me indeed. So I try to post about it whenever I see it is a valid answer to a posted question.

Comment: Mtgdb.Gui has got the filter to narrow down search to cards owned by user - which is what the question is about

Comment: edited an answer to remove details not specific to the question

Comment: Thank you for the revision and for stating your association.

Comment: Hey, we understand wanting to improve/update your post, but could you try to bundle up the edits a bit more, so that there's one larger edit instead of several spread out over a day or two? (I know it's hard to always get everything on the first try, though.)

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience I caused by chaotic frequent changes.

I will avoid several edits within reasonably short periods like 10-30 minutes, maybe hours. I can achive this by reviewing my edits more carefully before saving the change.

Is it ok or you need to have several days delay between changes?

Comment: @Nikolay Mostly the concern is those edits bump this thread a lot, though it seems that isn't your intention which is good. Regarding timeframes it's the opposite: Making several edits within a reasonably short timeframe is fine. Our preference is to avoid bumping this question multiple times over several days with minor edits each time.

Comment: Get it, really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: I would also suggest that you focus on just directly answering the question when you post here: how do you use your program to do what the OP wants? That last section with platforms, pricing, links, etc, is less important - you can just link once to your program's home page, and have all that information *there*, and update it there as necessary without bumping the threads here.

Comment: I see the information I put here such as Supported platforms, price and so on as
1) highly relevant as it helps reader to deside whether a he wants to explore further at all, e.g. Mac users will save some time by knowing it's for Windows.
2) Extremly unlikely to change to make me 'Bump' this thread in the future.

The way I see post footer now it's ideal and should not require further changes.

Comment: Only just now seeing your reply. You bumped both again, due to another change in the post footer, and many past edits reworked the footer too. I know you don't *plan* for this, but you've edited these answers far more than the vast majority of posts on the site, and we'd really like to calm things down. If you ever find yourself wanting to update the details again, please follow my previous suggestion unless there's really good reason not to (in which case maybe ask on [meta] first).

Answer (score 1):

iMtG for iOS has full blown inventory management system linked with Deck Builder. It is completely free for people with collections which would fit in 3 binders.

iMtG is made by myself (as someone who cares), it has had regular database updates since 2011. It is important as many other MTG collection manager apps failed to keep updating their databases over the years.

https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/imtg/id412798013?mt=8&at=10l74t